# wsimport can't authenticate from java

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, wsimport

I want use a `wsdl` webservice. For this, I get java code from this `wsdl` with `wsimport` and then create a java project.

In java code, I have all function that describes in documentation, but I dont't have any class for authentication and set userName and password.

Below code is the `.net` code:

```
ReportsClient service = new ReportsClient();

 ￼List<Object> allObject = new ￼￼￼￼￼￼List<Object>();

 service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "******"; 

service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "******";
```

I don't have any java class for set `userName` and `password`.

How can I set this object and then send my request and get response?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar situation and I've found this solution:

```
MySimpleService client = new MySimpleService();  
IMySimpleService port = client.getWSHttpBindingIMySimpleService();
((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "xiaozhuang");
((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "123456");
```

Source: http://blog.csdn.net/marvion/article/details/4015785

I hope it will help!